# What does this CSS mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know its simple but:

```
fieldset label.inline
```

does mean that all labls with the class inline inside an element with the class fieldset will be targeted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that all labels with the class inline inside a **fieldset element** will be targeted.

Check out [fieldsets](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/fieldset/)

`.fieldset` means `class="fieldset"`
`#fieldset` means `id="fieldset"`
`fieldset` means `<fieldset>`

Comment: +1 for emphasizing "fieldset element", that's where he made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It will select all labels, with a class of inline, inside all fieldsets. ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dk2yj/)***

```
<fieldset>
    <label class="inline">
    </label>
    <label class="outline">
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that all `<label class="inline">` inside `<fieldset>` will be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Matches the labels with class "inline" inside all the fieldsets.

Answer (score 1):

This selector means:

1. Find all the tags 'fieldset'.
2. Within them find all the tags 'label' having class 'inline'.
3. Apply styles (or functions, if you use CSS selectors eg. in jQuery to apply functions) to the elements matched in point 2.

Comment: Not really... most engines don't try to find every fieldset first.

Comment: That is exactly what I have said. In other words: find every 'label' tag having class 'inline' and being contained within any 'fieldset' tag. How did you understand what I have written? I may correct it not to create confusion.

Comment: I did not mean that selector works like the `fieldset, fieldset label.inline` selector - I hope this is clear when you are looking at my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just being too much of a nitpick because browsers usually read selectors right to left, but your answer is saying that they find all the fieldsets first before checking their children. Ignore me :P (Your comment is correct, though.)

Comment: No problem. I haven't considered the way browsers do it, just wanted to show the purpose of the selector in a way that is clear to people not familiar with CSS. +1 for how the browsers really do it

Answer (score 0):

[selectoracle](http://gallery.theopalgroup.com/selectoracle/) will explain this and other selectors

> Selects any label element with a class attribute that contains the word inline that is a descendant of a fieldset element